# SAP IQ 16.0 Load table encoding/charset

Tags: character-encoding, sybase, sap-iq

I try to load table from a txt file to Sybase IQ Server using `LOAD TABLE` statement. And I had encoding trouble getting inserted records like this **ћРР РђРЎРўРќРћ**. And I solved my problem using

`set temporary option DEFAULT_ISQL_ENCODING = 'UTF8';`

But now we got new server and this doesn't solve my problem any more. Whatever I do I get encoding problem.

`SELECT PROPERTY ('charset')` outputs `'utf8'` on both servers.

`SELECT @@version` outputs:

> Sybase IQ/15.4.0.3027/130221/P/ESD 3/RS6000MP/AIX 6.1.0/64bit/2013-02-21 11:27:49
>   ***old server***
>
> SAP IQ/16.0.0.808/141110/P/sp08.20/Enterprise Linux64 - x86_64 - 2.6.18-194.el5/64bit/2014-11-10 12:47:58
>   ***new server***

Answer (score 0):

From where are you trying to load your txt file?

Your problems exists because you have a carriage return in your file, that happens when you send a file with (ћРР РђРЎРўРќРћ characters) from windows to unix. If you are trying to load the file from unix...try executing dos2unix file.txt, then try loading again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by changing my file to format ANSI with notepad, and then when I loaded my file this was correct.

Property and Version from my DB:
**SELECT PROPERTY ('charset'):** ISO_8859-1:1987
**SELECT @@version:** Sybase IQ/15.1.0.5034/091223/P/ESD 2/Enterprise Linux64 - x86_64 - 2.6.9-67.0.4.ELsmp/64bit/2009-12-23 09:34:56